# Enable gzip compression for static files in aiohttp

Tags: python, http-compression, aiohttp

I'm trying to enable compression in aiohttp in static files too. I tried creating a custom response:

```
import aiohttp

class GzipResponse(aiohttp.web.StreamResponse):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.enable_compression()
```

and added it as factory to the static routes:

```
app.router.add_static("prefix", "path", response_factory=GzipResponse)
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it doesn't work because currently `sendfile` approach doesn't switches to fallback if compression is set.

Comment: I can be wrong, but it seems that `aiohttp.file_sender.FileSender._sendfile_fallback()` method seems to not compress the sent content.

Comment: Yes.
Personally I don't care about static file compressing right now -- I have more important issues in my todo list.